# Integrating live video streaming in .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, html5-video

I have another current best practices question.

I've been looking at a significant number of options and want to hear from some people who have experience with this scenario.

My client is creating a site similar to the ustream site, where we will be show video content, and also allowing clients to broadcast live video and distribute it to the user base. I think I have the static video content figured out, using Amazon CDN to deliver to an embedded HTML5 video player. But what wold be the best method to create endpoints for users to upstream their video content and then distribute it live?

We had looked in to bit gravity earlier, but we would end up have to keep creating/destroying endpoints as the need varys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have similar requirement as you had. Can you please suggest me what should i use and how? I never implemented live streaming in .net web application.